# Interface classes and factory functions in C++

Tags: c++

In Meyers Effective C++ item 31 (p147 in my 3rd edition) he talks about interface classes.  He shows an example of a Person class with pure virtual methods and a derived class RealPerson.  It looks something like this, though I've simplified it and added trivial implementations.

```
#include <string>

class Person {
public:
    virtual ~Person() {};
    virtual std::string name() const = 0;    
};

class RealPerson : public Person {
public:
    RealPerson(const std::string& name) : theName(name) {}
    virtual ~RealPerson() {};
    virtual std::string name() const { return theName; }

private:
    std::string theName;
};
```

He then goes on to say that we can easily create a 'factory function' to create real people:

```
std::shared_ptr<Person>Person::create(const std::string& name) // EDIT - removed tr1::
{
    return std::shared_ptr<Person>(new RealPerson(name));
}
```

Why would I want to use this 'create' function when I can just instantiate the RealPerson class in the normal way?

Also, why are the derived class methods 'virtual'.

### EDIT

Thanks for the comments. I understand the purpose (now) but I don't see how that differs from any base class in any hierarchy - are such factory functions typical in all base classes?  It also has the feel of something of a kludge, not part of a language. But I am relatively new to C++ so that might just be my problem.

Comment: You don't need `std::tr1::shared_ptr` anymore, since C++11 `shared_ptr` is member of the std namespace: `std::shared_ptr`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### it's for picking the right subclass when you have more than one.

And keeping that logic in just one place to make it maintainable (OO+procedural dude!!)

If you've got a database or data entry screen that can store or allow entry of more than one person, when you want to write a function to read the screen to create the new person object, or, load the record from the database, the first line can't be 'new RealPerson(name);'. The data entry screen or database record might be talking about 'ImaginaryFriend(name)'. This would be given away by, in the simplest cases, a dropdown on the screen or a code/string in a column on the database.

And you can't create 'new Person'  - it's virtual.

So before you start loading the fields or database columns into your new object, you make the new one by calling the factory and passing it a 'code' (or other 'giveaway' to what the object is that is consistent), which, in the most basic situation, will be examined by the factory (say by a simple switch statement) to figure out which 'new' to call. This way, your program isn't littered with switch statements to make the right kind of concrete object.

Of course, it can get way more complicated than that. This is just a situation that, if you do use inheritance, you *will* have to deal with when building the right subclass.

Comment: So it seems that these factory classes are general to derived classes, not specific to interface classes (see my edit to the question). Is that right?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly correct. Regarding your thought this is a kludge, several credible people agree with you that this is a language limitation. http://norvig.com/design-patterns/design-patterns.pdf (search for Factory). Unfortunately ... the answer is switching to Lisp. Have fun!

Answer (score 3):

If you instantiate a `RealPerson` in the real way, you must know at compile time that you want a `RealPerson`. The factory method returns a `shared_ptr<Person>`, so the code can decide at run time what kind of `Person` to create; the method might decide to give you a `FictionalPerson`, `PlatosIdealPerson`, `LongDeadPerson` or whatever, depending on the situation.

And the derived class methods are virtual because you might want to derive other classes, like `YoungRealPerson`, from `RealPerson`.

Answer (score 2):

> Why would I want to use this 'create' function when I can just instantiate the RealPerson class in the normal way?

So that users don't need to know about the concrete types that implement the `Person` interface; they only need to know about the factory function(s) that create the sort of person they want.

> Also, why are the derived class methods `virtual`

Because they're declared `virtual` in the base class. It's optional whether you also declare them `virtual` in the derived class; they're virtual whether you do or not.

Comment: The last sentence is not right AFAIK. If one wouldnt declare them virtual again one couldnt provide another implementation in yet another child class.

Comment: @Paranaix: I don't know what you mean. Declaring them `virtual` in the base class means that they are also virtual in any derived class that overrides them, whether or not the override is explicitly declared `virtual`; which is what the last sentence says.

Answer (score 2):

One of simple reasons would be that you expand the create function to something like this:

```
std::tr1::shared_ptr<Person>Person::create(const std::string & obj,const std::string& name)
{

    if(obj=="RealPerson")
        return std::tr1::shared_ptr<Person>(new RealPerson(name));
    else if ( obj == "ImaginaryPerson")
        return std::tr1::shared_ptr<Person>(new ImaginaryPerson(name)); 
      // Lets assume there exists some other class ImaginaryPerson: public Person .. 
    return std::tr1::shared_ptr<Person>();
}
```

And by calling the create function with different obj you could create different kind of Person objects.

The base class is marked virtual because someone could want to expand the RealPerson class to RealPersonWithHair class which has different `name()` implementation.

Answer (score 1):

1. Your code might be a client of a library which publishes the `Person` interface and doesn't even know of the existence of a `RealPerson` class. Alternatively, the library might have an optimised implementation for people whose name starts with "John", and might be returning a `JohnPerson` instead of a `RealPerson` based on the name. You, as the client, don't need to know, and shouldn't care.

   Note that this need not be a strict library-client scenario, it can also be different modules/parts of one application. Still, "coding to interfaces, not implementations" is good practice, because it enforces encapsulation and facilitates unit testing.
2. "Once virtual, always virtual." When a function is declared `virtual` in a base class, its overriders are automatically virtual, whether you put the keyword by them or not. It's good practice to put it there as a reminder, however. In C++11, you're also strongly encouraged to provide the `override` specifier as well, so that the compiler checks whether you're actually overriding when you intend to.

Answer (score 1):

You can find information on factory functions in [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_design_pattern) or in numerous books on design patterns. In short, it is a constructor with diverse behavior which will return you a different object, depending on the arguments (a RealPerson or a FootballPlayer or any other class derived from Person).

The virtual keyword in the derived class is not needed. It is a reminder that the method is virtual.